# Javascript ativando o action do formulário

Tags: javascript, html

Situação:
Tem o formulário e uma das opções que eu quero é que ele de um resultado da soma de variáveis automaticamente clicando num botão ou pode ser sem clicar, apenas o usuário só digitando os valores.

O problema é:
ele já esta ativando o action para a pagina de processamento em php sem o usuário terminar de completar o formulário. Como poderia fazer para mostrar o resultado da soma em baixo do botão somar (o mesmo que está ativando o action)?

código no header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    function calcula(){  
    var val1 = document.getElementById("pa").value;  
    var val2 = document.getElementById("di").value;
    var val3 = document.getElementById("insc").value;  
    var val4 = document.getElementById("outr").value;
    var soma = parseFloat(val1)+parseFloat(val2)+parseFloat(val3)+parseFloat(val4);  
    document.write("" + soma);  
}  
</script>
```

agora o código dentro do formulário html que chama a função acima:

```
<legend>Calcular total.</legend>    
<button id="calcular" onclick="calcula()">Calcular</button>
```

Aceito sugestões para se fazer de outra forma ou outra linguagem.

Comment: Nada nesse código está acionando o action, mas o `document.write` está sobrescrevendo o documento inteiro.

Comment: O usuário coloca os números nas variáveis, gostaria de um botão ou mesmo que a soma desses campos fossem feitos e mostrados. o código ai faz parte dentro do formulário em HTML, eu poderia usar `alert(soma);` ele mostra o resultado (como eu quero) só que depois o formulário da o action para eu tratar as informações em outra pagina PHP, mas eu não quero isso. Quero apenas mostrar o resultado dessas variáveis somadas automaticamente dentro do próprio formulário que o usuário está preenchendo.

Comment: Uma coisa q tb pode ser feita é colocar a chamada da função calculo no onchange dos input dos valores, assim vc tem o valor da soma antes de pressionar o botão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por defeito, o `<button></button>` submete o formulário quando se carrega no botão.

Este comportamento pode ser alterado indicando `type="button"` ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5FW8N/)).

```
<button id="calcular_btn" type="button" onclick="calcular()">X</button>
```

Alternativamente, pode-se suprimir a submissão devolvendo o valor `false` no evento do botão ([jsfiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/4gnxB/2/), [jsfiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/LER4w/)).

```
<button id="calcular_btn" onclick="calcular(); return false;">X</button>
```

Existe ainda uma terceira forma de suprimir a submissão: através do `preventDefault` ([jsfiddle DOM simples](http://jsfiddle.net/HzvpS/1/), [jsfiddle jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/4gnxB/3/)).

```
$('#calcular_btn').click(function (e) {
    calcular();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Excelente! bastou um simples `return false` dentro do botão.
Então removi o `document.write` e ao invés dele usei `document.getElementById("soma").value = soma;` ele retorna o resultado para um campo de texto HTML `<input type="text" name="soma" id="soma">` que fica em baixo das outras variáveis  como eu queria.

Answer (score 0):

Se o que você precisa é cancelar o envio do formulário o ideal é adicionar o código abaixo ao seu [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)

```
document.getElementById('id-do-form').onsubmit = function() {
    return false;
}
```